# What Azure Ad Role do I need in order to be able to Add and Edit User Extensions Properties?

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, roles

Using Graph Explorer (with pretty much all permissions granted) or Powershell, I keep getting Access Denied errors when trying to patch users.

The request I'm trying to make is **PATCH** https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me  ( or any other user )
with a payload of

```json
{
    "extension_5c14xxxxxxxf55ae1de26ae8d9496a_buildings": "555-555-555"

}
```

From experimentation with other things, it appears that I can't write extension properties or anything else to users (including me).

What Role do I need in order to be able to add and edit user attributes?

I currently have Application Administrator, Cloud Application Administrator, Tenant Creator, Application Attribute Administrator, and a bunch of others that seem less relevant.

**Update:**  Just expanding on this a little.

I know this can be done with the application, because another user in my organization with full admin permissions can add values to a user and those values I was able to see in the JWT when authorizing.

I keep getting access denied errors, but he always got `204` status code with no content.  The documentation says this is correct.

To be clear I am almost 100% sure that this is not related to permissions I grant the application.  I have granted the application permissions to do just about anything it want, and it makes no difference.

I don't know if it matters, but I am in an organization that has an Azure AD Premium P1 subscription.  I am able to grant admin permissions that are delegated, but not those at the application level.  However, when I had someone with admin permissions attempt to grant those permissions, I still was unable add extension properties to user from the graph api.

**Further information:**

When made a **User Administrator** in Azure, I am able to do this.  However when combining the User Administrator action permissions that appear relevant into a custom azure role, and then adding me to that role, I get permission denied errors.

Answer (score -1):

Hope you have created an extension attribute before updating it : [Azure AD cmdlets to work with extension attributes | Microsoft Learn.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0)

An app can only update users extension data if `User.ReadWrite.All` permission is granted and if the user has supported Azure AD administrative role

Check the following to update extension attribute:

**GET**  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userObjId>?$select= extension_cbaxxxa01_Engineering`  to check its value

[image]

To update:

**PATCH** **`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/548cxxxd-xx5daf`**

```
{
    "extension_cbaexxx50aa01_Engineering": "ECE"
}
```

[image]

[image]

If you are trying to change custom security attributes , [Attribute Assignment Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#attribute-assignment-administrator)
Or Attribute Definition Administrator role should be assigned as even Global admin do not have permissions to assign or read custom security atributes.

**Reference** :[What are custom security attributes in Azure AD? (Preview) - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/custom-security-attributes-overview#steps-to-use-custom-security-attributes)

Comment: Thank you for your reply - `An app can only update users extension data if User.ReadWrite.All permission is granted and if the user has supported Azure AD administrative role`  - What is a supported Administrative role that covers this.  I keep getting access denied using the same query as you have.

Comment: I have created the extension attribute on the application.  I am not able or do not know how to create it on the user.

Comment: You can check out these steps to add extension attribute to user after creating it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0. Next steps to update it are given in answer.

Comment: I realize I have been using the phrase 'Extension Attribute', which, given Microsoft's recent addition of custom 'Security Extension Attributes', could've been confusion.  What I'm looking at is `extension properties` as I want this value accessible in a jwt.